# Forecasting a "chaotic" time series

Tags: time-series, self-study, forecasting, descriptive-statistics, particle-filter

Here are four graphs,

1, autocorrelation, autocovariance, partial-correlation and cross-correlation calculated from a time series are given.

2, The time series

I need to do some predictions on them.

My questions are 4 :

1, I do not quite understand what these four graphs can tell or show. Can anyone explain?

2, Does the four subplots tell if it is appropriate to do forecasting for the time series

3, If so, any method to do forecasting?

4, I am wondering if particle filter can be used.

I am a little clueless about this problem.

[image: descriptive stats]

[image: The time series which seems "chaotic"]

Comment: Hi there, if you have a truly chaotic system, i.e. one that meets the definition of a complex system (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_system) you will not be able to forecast it using time series.

Answer (score 1):

1) 1, I do not quite understand what these four graphs can tell or show. Can anyone explain?

The auto-correlation is the ratio of the co-variance to the variance. It tells you the unconditional impact
of a lag on the observed series . The Partial Auto-correlation tells you the conditional importance/effect of a lag given all intermediate(lesser) lags much akin to a partial regression coefficient. The cross-correlation reflects the relationship between two series for different lags. It is totally meaningless when dealing with time series due to auto-correlation within the 
individual series.

2) it is not possible to answer your question until one forms either ARIMA models or ARMAX  Models for causative problems

3)The method is called BOX-JENKINS

4)Which identifies the appropriate filter to separate observed data to signal and noise.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand why cross-correlation would be meaningless for time series, could you expand on that please?

Comment: @nico Cross-correlation tests require joint normalitywhich requires normalityforeach series.Normality requires (among other things!) independence for each and every observation in the series. Your Time series data the data is (probably) auto-correlated violating the assumption of independence.You might start with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udny_Yule and "Why do we get nonsense correlation between time sries".You might also read http://autobox.com/AFSUniversity/afsuFrameset.htmhttp://autobox.com/AFSUniversity/afsuFrameset.htm highlighting the difference between Box-Jenkins and Regression.